# How come self gets updated inside object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a object that I create two instances of:

```
    var generalGraph = new graph(generalFunnel)
    generalGraph.draw("#conversion");

    var invoicingGraph = new graph(invoicingFunnel)
    invoicingGraph.draw("#invoicing")
```

Here is the object (note that this is highly simplified to make it easier to understand) the comments are the  console-outputs.

```
graph = function(funnel){
    this.funnel = funnel.conversions
    mySelf = this

    this.draw = function(selector){
        console.log(mySelf.funnel)
        //generalGraph ["Användare", "Påbörjat Onboarding", "Skapat oganisation", "Skapat användare", "Kom tillbaka", "Köpt"]
        //invoicingGraph ["Användare", "Påbörjat Onboarding", "Skapat oganisation", "Kom tillbaka", "Köpt"]
        nv.addGraph(function() {

            console.log(mySelf.funnel)
            //generalGraph ["Användare", "Påbörjat Onboarding", "Skapat oganisation", "Kom tillbaka", "Köpt"]
            //invoicingGraph ["Användare", "Påbörjat Onboarding", "Skapat oganisation", "Kom tillbaka", "Köpt"]
        });
    }

}
```

For some reason, when I do `generalGraph.draw`, it uses the funnel from `invoicingFunnel`. Why? And how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: I don't know, the reason i do mySelf = this is that, this is sometimes changed, for example inside nv.addGraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mySelf` is a global variable, you're missing a `var` before it. For this reason both of your `graph` instances use the same mySelf value.

Change:

```
mySelf = this
```

To

```
var mySelf = this
```

- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it) on the differences between using and ommitting var.
- You can prevent these errors in the future by using [strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it) which will spot these errors for you.
- Omitting semicolons in JavaScript is possible but is considered very risky because of [the complicated rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) it involves. It is generally frowned upon to do it today.
- Similarly - constructor names in JS typically start with a capital letter. Your constructor should probably be defined with the `var` keyword as well.